# Pandas; calculate mean and append mean to original frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where the first column is a country label and the second column contains a number. Most countries are in the list multiple times. In want to do 2 operations:

1. Calculate the mean for every country
2. Append the mean of every country as a third column

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: some data , the expected result and what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` by 'Country' and use `transform` to apply a function to that group which will return an index aligned to the original df

```
df.groupby('Country').transform('mean')
```

See the online docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
df.groupby(['Country']).mean()
```